# Preservation of (co)limits under taking derived categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a diagram of $R$-linear $1$-categories, indexed by a finite poset $I$.  (If this matters, assume that the $A_i$ have finitely many objects).

Given an $R$-linear $1$-category $A$, let $D(A)$ be the infinity category $Fun(A, ch(R))$, localized at the quasi-isomorphisms.  The reason for this notation is that if we assume $A$ has finitely many objects, then we can view $A$ equivalently as a semi-simple $R$-algebra with idempotents indexed by the objects, and $D(-)$ is the ordinary unbounded derived category of the abelian category of modules over said algebra.

**Question:** do we have $D(colim A_i)= holim D(A_i)$?    (Note that I am distinguishing here between the $1$-categorical colimit and the infinity-categorical homotopy limit.)

Comment: Indexed by a finite *set* $I$ or a finite category ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi A finite poset, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It essentially going to boils down to the question of wether the colimit of the $A_i$ is a homotopy colimits of dg-categories. So sometime yes, but in general no.

Comment: A línear category with one object is the same as an algebra, but not necessarily semi-simple.